# Move American Time zone to top of php array

Tags: php

I Need to rework an PHP array of time zones.  I am trying to move the american timezones to the top of the array.  How do you single out iterations and either remove them or reorder the array?

Comment: Please include some sample data in your question :) Current data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you know the exact values of americanTimezones and stored those in an array $moveUsToTheTop, and that the current disordered array is $timezones, the following should reposition those values at $moveUsToTheTop at the beginning of the array

```
foreach ($moveUsToTheTop as $americanTimezone){
    $pos = array_search($americanTimezone, $timezones);
    unset($timezones[$pos]);
    array_unshift($timezones, $americanTimezone);
}
```